# New way to detect Facebook API user currency

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Since **currency** field is [deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/05/01/facebook-login-updates-further-protect-privacy/) form January 08, 2019, you can find **user_currency** in **payment_mobile_pricepoints** object.

Don't forget to add payment_mobile_pricepoints into requested fields list

```
FB.api("/me", {fields:"payment_mobile_pricepoints"}, function(result){
    var currencyCode = result['payment_mobile_pricepoints']['user_currency'];
});
```

Hope it helps to somebody

Comment: [Self-Answers are actually encouraged here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) - but you should at least phrase the above as a _question_ of some sort first.

Answer (score 5):

Since **currency** field is [deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/05/01/facebook-login-updates-further-protect-privacy/) form January 08, 2019, you can find **user_currency** in **payment_mobile_pricepoints** object.

Don't forget to add payment_mobile_pricepoints into requested fields list

```
FB.api("/me", {fields:"payment_mobile_pricepoints"}, function(result){
    var currencyCode = result['payment_mobile_pricepoints']['user_currency'];
});
```

Hope it helps to somebody