# Facebook graph api doesn't return currency

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-graph-api

I have problem getting user local currency and usd-exchange rate from facebook, so this one: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/currency/

I'm trying to show my shop prices in local currency, just like fb shows prices in local currency in its own purchase dialog after facebook-purchase is launched.

I'm trying to get currency like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.12/me?fields=id,name,currency&access_token=...

(Actually using Unity and Facebook's Unity SDK to do this, but exactly same thing happens when using url above.)

That have definitely worked before. I've also tried api version 3.2. It returns id and name, but no currency info of any kind. But it doesn't give any error message either, as it does with invalid fields.

I really can't find any useful info or help to this. Does getting currency require special permissions these days? But I can't find anything currency related from FB dev console App Review / Permissions and Features either.

Thanks!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/ has the field listed as deprecated, and when you hover over the lock symbol, it will show a tooltip saying, “Only available to the following apps: …”, and then it lists your apps that can still access this field (if you have any), those that were created before a certain date.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.0 says it was deprecated in that version.

Comment: Thank you for this. Actually that lock hover tooltip is listing our app as "visible to following apps", but still no luck getting it :( Also thinking of future when that gets totally deprecated, I wonder is there any replacing method. I found out that "payment_mobile_pricepoints" returns also user currency code, but no exchange rate so that is not so useful.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to my own question. It just seems that currency info is no longer available.

Starting from January 8th (2019) that field is no longer available for any apps:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/05/01/facebook-login-updates-further-protect-privacy/

There's discussion about this issue here, without any solution so far (may require having FB developer account to access):
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/285780305453757/

There are some workarounds to get user currency like:
[New way to detect Facebook API user currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126920/new-way-to-detect-facebook-api-user-currency)

But that doesn't give you exchange rate to USD, so that isn't too helpful showing prices in local currency before Facebook's own purchase dialog is displayed.

Very unfortunate. Still, if someone knows way to get local currency and exchange rate that will surely match exchange rates used by FB, please let me know.